# How can I make a dependent dropdown?

Tags: google-sheets

I work for a builder. I'm attempting to keep track of work completed by labourers at job sites. I'm trying to create dependent dropdowns.

I have two sheets:

1. `Drop Downs`  contains lists that are used to populate the dropdowns in the sheet `Paul`
2. `Paul` tracks Paul's hours for the week.

#### 1. Drop Downs

`Drop Downs` has 3 columns containing the following:

1. `Jobs` contains a list of about 30 job/site names.
2. `Work` is a list of about 70 work items/tasks.
3. `Hrs.` is a sequence of 50 times: 0.25 to 12.5 hrs in 0.25 hr increments.

###### Sample `Drop Downs`

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Jobs** |  | **Work** |  | **Hrs** |
| **2** | - |  | ADMIN Meeting |  | 0.25 |
| **3** | #Admin |  | ADMIN Study |  | 0.50 |
| **4** | #Finance |  | CEILING Cornice |  | 0.75 |
| **5** | #Holiday |  | DECK Balustrade |  | 1.00 |
| **6** | #Meeting |  | DECK Handrail Post |  | 1.25 |
| **7** | 1 Road City |  | FIXOUT Arcs |  | 1.50 |
| **8** | 2 Road City |  | FRAME Bracing |  | 1.75 |
| **9** | 3 Road City |  | PREP Scaffold |  | 2.00 |
| **10** | 4 Road City |  | ROOF Beam |  | 2.25 |
| **11** | 5 Road City |  | CLEAN Pack up |  | 2.50 |

<sub>**`Drop Downs` Sheet**    *(click image to rotate & enlarge)*</sub>
(Click image to Rotate and enlarge)**
[image]

#### 2. Paul

`Paul` contains tables where Paul's hours are recorded. There is one table for each day and all the tables share the same headings:

1. `Day` lists the weekday (eg. Thursday).
2. `Hrs Ttl` is the sum of the `Hrs` column for that day.
3. `Date` is the date "dd/mm/yy"
4. `Job` contains a dropdown from the `Jobs` range: `'Drop Downs'!A2:A`
5. `Work` contains a dropdown from the `Work` range: `'Drop Downs'!C2:C`
6. `Hrs` contains a dropdown from the `Hrs` range: `'Drop Downs'!E2:E`

###### Sample `Paul`

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Day** | **Hrs Ttl** | **Date** | **Job** | **Work** | **Hrs** |
| **2** | Thursday | 8 | 22/09/22 | 1 Road City | DECK Handrail Post | 4 |
| **3** |  |  |  | 1 Road City | DECK Handrail Post | **4** |
| **4** |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **5** | Friday | 9 | 23/09/22 | 1 Road City | FIX OUT General | 4 |
| 6 |  |  |  | 14 Road City | CLADDING | 4 |
| 7 |  |  |  | #Travel | ADMIN Meeting | 1 |

<sub>**`Paul` Sheet**    *(click image to enlarge)*</sub>
[image]

At the moment the `Job` dropdown is populated with a list of 30 job sites but Paul is only working at a few of them.  Also the dropdown `Work` is populated with about 70 items but only a subset are performed per site and they vary from site to site.

What I want to do is limit the `Job` list to those that Paul works on and have the `Work` dropdown be dependent on the `Job` selected. That way Paul can choose the right `Job` and the `Work` options will be limited to a few options rather than scrolling through a long list each time.

[Link to example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18paIpHxPGZz62aH10vs-AQo0pvbvX-vezAwnVk3nqJU/edit?usp=sharing): Red tabs denote the original problem;  Green tabs the current solution.

Answer (score 2):

Setting aside the specifics of your use case, the way to create dependent dropdowns is approached the same way.

The first dropdown is used as a FILTER for the options for the second dropdown and so forth.

Assuming your dropdown `Jobs` is populated from a list in `lists!A2:A`:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Jobs** |  |  |  |
| **2** | Job 01 |  |  |  |
| **3** | Job 02 |  |  |  |
| **4** | Job 03 |  |  |  |

Your dependent dropdown `tasks` need to be filtered based on the `Jobs` category selected therefore the `tasks` must be associated/tagged with their appropriate category. You could approach creating the association in various ways.

**All of the following achieve the same result:**

1. Create a **separate task list** for each job category;
2. Use a **common task list** and a checkbox for each job category;
3. Create a **two-column list** with 'category:task' value pairs

Whichever approach you take, associated tasks with a `Job` category allows returning a list of tasks based on a selected `Job` category.

An array formula is placed in a helper column that checks what value is entered in each of your `Jobs` dropdowns and then returns an array of lists, one for each dropdown/row.

For example, assuming your `Jobs` dropdowns are in sheet `data` in the first column, `data!A2:A`, below are the example formulas that are used to populate your dependent dropdown.

The formulas are similar but adapted depending on the approach you take to managing the relationship between your tasks and their `Job` category.

##### 1.   Separate list for each category

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Jobs** | **Job 01** | **Job 02** | **Job 03** |
| **2** | Job 01 | Task 01 | Task 01 | Task 02 |
| **3** | Job 02 | Task 02 | Task 03 | Task 03 |
| **4** | Job 03 | Task 04 | Task 05 | Task 04 |

###### Separate list formula in `lists!E2`

```
=BYROW(data!A2:A, LAMBDA(r, TOROW(IFERROR(
   INDEX(B2:D,,MATCH(r,B1:1,0))),1)))
```

##### 2.   Common task list and checkboxes

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Jobs** | **Tasks** | **Job 01** | **Job 02** | **Job 03** |  |
| **2** | Job 01 | Task 01 | **`☑`** | **`☑`** | ☐ |  |
| **3** | Job 02 | Task 02 | **`☑`** | **`☑`** | **`☑`** |  |
| **4** | Job 03 | Task 03 | **`☑`** | ☐ | **`☑`** |  |
| **5** |  | Task 04 | ☐ | **`☑`** | **`☑`** |  |

###### Common task list formula in `lists!F2`

```
=BYROW(data!A2:A, LAMBDA(r, TOROW(IFERROR(
  FILTER(B2:B,INDEX(C2:E,,MATCH(r,C1:1,0)))),1)))
```

##### 3.   Two column 'category:task' value pairs

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Jobs** | **Category** | **Task** |  |
| **2** | Job 01 | Job 01 | Task 01 |  |
| **3** | Job 02 | Job 01 | Task 02 |  |
| **4** | Job 03 | Job 01 | Task 04 |  |
| **5** |  | Job 02 | Task 01 |  |
| **6** |  | Job 02 | Task 03 |  |
| **7** |  | Job 02 | Task 05 |  |
| **8** |  | Job 03 | Task 02 |  |
| **9** |  | Job 03 | Task 03 |  |
| **10** |  | Job 03 | Task 04 |  |

###### 'category:task' formula in `lists!E2`

```
=BYROW(data!A2:A, LAMBDA(r, 
  TOROW(FILTER(C2:C,B2:B=r),1)))
```

Similarly if you wanted another dropdown dependent on the `Task` you would approach it the same way however now the `Task` would become the category for other lists of values.

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively straightforward.

Assuming you are using data validation for your dropdown, the first dropdown `work site` is already working. What you need to do is to create an additional table that has all the workers that can be assigned to that `work site`.

You can then use the FILTER function for a site like:

```
=FILTER(B1:B7,A1:A7=$D$9)
```

where `B1:B7` contains the names of the workers, `A1:A7` contains the `work site`s that they can be assigned to, and `D9` contains the `work site` selected in the dropdown.

I've created a simple example:  [Link to example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18q7R5j7rBSioYepApyVv0vtYwoGDyHHtVhQ3NUqX3IQ/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should have shared an example of my sheet. It has an example of what we're currently using but in the "drop downs" tab we'd like the "work" dropdown to be specific to the job site. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18paIpHxPGZz62aH10vs-AQo0pvbvX-vezAwnVk3nqJU/edit?usp=sharing